# PHP/ASP network information manager for development team

Tags: website

I'm searching for a way to manage my network, to store only information about Server/VM list, every user/admin of each and maybe information of what has happened on each VM, the main software installed and other useful information. It's to manage a development team environment.

I want a free or open source package/site in PHP or ASP.NET.

I don't need to know more than the IP/name of servers, maybe the domain but not everything about routing or that kind of stuff.

---

Sample of data :

20 Development VM (for web, winform or release compilation)
40 Release Server
20 users (Developer, Analyst, Manager)
5 systems

I want a web way (different than excel sheet) for managing links and right between VMs, Users and Systems.

Answer (score 2):

To be perfectly honest; this is something a wiki is fairly well suited to (and is what I use) if it's a fairly small environment and you don't need complex user permissions management of who can see what content on the documentation system (though some wiki systems probably now have that functionality).

Unless of course you're looking for some sort of automatic discovery/documentation, which isn't clear from your question, really.

Comment: I had a sample of data, what I want to "manage". You think an internal wiki could do the job?